# simple angular service confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

To put it simply angular services always confuse me and I seem to get them working by trial and error. I'd like to know why in this case data returns undefined.

App module :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['services']);
```

Service:

```
//creating a service module
var appServices = angular.module('services', []);

appServices.factory('Data', function(){
return {message : "I am data"}
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl',['Data',
function($scope, Data){
    //get data from the service
    $scope.data = Data;
    console.log(Data);

}]);

app.controller('secondCtrl',['Data',
function($scope, Data){
    //get data from the service
    $scope.data = Data;

}]);
```

If I console log data I just get "undefined" .
Im just trying to do a simple example to return the object {message:"i am data"} 
so that

$scope.data = Data;

then in the view

data.message = "i am data"

Would really appreciate an explanation of why this does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not injecting `$scope` into the controller. Change it to this:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', [
    '$scope', // There should be an element of this array for each parameter
    'Data',
    function($scope, Data){
        //get data from the service
        $scope.data = Data;
        console.log(Data);
    }
]);
```

As you're only injecting the `Data` service it gets mapped to the `$scope` parameter of the controller function, and nothing gets mapped to the `Data` parameter (and since a variable that has not been assigned a value implicitly has the value `undefined`, you see `undefined`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use above answer but you can use

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, Data){

    //get data from the service
    $scope.data = Data;
    console.log(Data);
});
```

this will work fine no need for passing array of services and function in controller as second argument just function will work fine.